# Find in all sub directories

Tags: centos, ssh, directory, find, recursive

I have a directory with many sub directories,
I want to find a file in this directories so I use this command:

```
find ./ -name test.php
```

but this command search just in the top level directory,

how can I search in all sub directories too?

Comment: The command you're posting does search all sub directories. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: This should work as expected - what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @MajAfy Can you change the post so it states what it is you want? Just finding where the files are so that you can use a command to find then seem tying the horse behind the wagon. I suspect that you are trying to find them so you can do something in a script with them. However that is a guess since the OP lacks that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command will you used will search the directories (including all sub-directories) for files named `test.php`.

It **will** search subdirectories, assuming you have the rights needed.

However you might want to change `-name` to `-iname` so that you can find files regardless of the case. (e.g. also find `Test.php`, `test.PHP` or `teSt.phP`)

You might also want to add `-ls` or `-print`. Printing the file location when found is the default for many 'finds', but it is a good habit to explicitly do this.

Examples:

```
mkdir footest1
cd footest1
touch test.php
touch TesT.pHp
cd ..

find ./ -name test.php -print
./footest1/test.php

find ./ -iname test.php -print
./footest1/test.php
./footest1/TesT.pHp
```

If you are going to feed the output from find to another program then consider `-print0`.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.
Does your user have privileges to cd into and read the sub dirs and the file you want?

Answer (score 0):

Also you cold try

```
ls -lR | grep test.php
```